# Why set the whole `hints` variable to 0?

Tags: c, sockets

I am reading Beej's guide to network programming and in [chapter 5.1](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html), in the `showip.c` program I see the following line of code:
 `memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);`

After a discussion on the ##c channel on freenode I deducted that the reasoning of that `memset` call could be to set the value of `hints.ai_flags` to `0`(note that the program works fine I remove that line and I explicitly initialize `hints.ai_flags` to 0). If this is true, why does he need to set the whole struct to `0`?

This is the full source:

```
/*
** showip.c -- show IP addresses for a host given on the command line
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int status;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: showip hostname\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

    for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        char *ipver;

        // get the pointer to the address itself,
        // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        } else { // IPv6
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }

        // convert the IP to a string and print it:
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
        printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res); // free the linked list

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's required by `getaddrinfo()` function documentation (where you pass your `hints` variable as parameter). From [man getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo):

> All the other fields in the structure pointed to by `hints` must contain either `0` or a `NULL` pointer, as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are only going to fill/use/**initialize** some of the fields of the struct, giving `0` to the other fields prevents reading an **uninitialzied** variable, and sometimes `0` is the default value for those variables.

> note that the program works fine I remove that line and I explicitly initialize `hints.ai_flags` to `0`

Not necessarily, if you are on linux, I suggest using [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) to detect reads to uninitialized variables, since that causes undefined behavior, the behavior could be that nothing wierd happens.